# Datadog monitor to group an alert by request query parameter value

Tags: datadog

I'm looking to create a monitor that would group an alert based on a query parameter value from a servlet request.

Example

http://service/feedpet?animal=dog

I realize that the way to do this with a path parameter would be to use a metric for trace.servlet.request and avg on the resource_name, something like:

http://service/feedpet/animal/${animal}
`avg:trace.servlet.request.hits{env:some,resource_name:get_/feedpet/animal/_animal_}`

What I'm looking to do is the same thing, but using query parameters but I don't see any info in the Datadog docs that to indicate how to group by query parameters.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar question open but about path parameters. Could you please elaborate the solution you provided for that? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "APM-Monitor" based on APM instead of Metric.

Define Query: "Trace Analytics"

Filter: env:some,resource_name:get_/feedpet/animal

Group by: **http.query.string**

Answer (score 0):

I don't want anyone else to go through the same pain as I did.

Here is the way to do it:

- Select "Trace Analytics" instead of "Metrics"
- Select the Service, Environment, and the Resource
- Select http.url_details.path and choose the right URI

You can optionally group by if needed (or leave it as "everything")