# Create metric grouping by path parameter in datadog

Tags: metrics, datadog

Is it possible to create a metric from an endpoint in datadog and group by a path variable? For example, given `/animals/_animalName`, I'd like to sum by `_animalName` and have a graph with as many lines or stacked bars as values in that variable. The idea is to be able to automatically extract values from the usage of that endpoint, instead of having to explicitly create metrics from code with tags and add the values to them. Something like this below (the graph type is irrelevant, but I'd like to be able to extract those values).

[image]

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73937231/datadog-monitor-to-group-an-alert-by-request-query-parameter-value) where the original poster mentions that there is a way but I’m not able to do it myself. Thanks!